# CustomTaskPane Visibility in Outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, customtaskpane

I have a custom TaskPane in Outlook.  When the user toggles the visibility, I record it in the settings object so that the next time Outlook starts it will be shown/hidden as the user left it.

[`CustomTaskPane.VisibleChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.customtaskpane.visiblechanged.aspx) is raised in each of the following scenarios

1. The user clicks the X in the top right corner of the task pane
2. `TaskPane.Visible` is set in response to the user pressing a toggle button in the ribbon
3. The user presses the File menu button on the top left

The first two ways, the user clearly meant to hide the task pane.  The third way the user was just trying to go to the menu screen (perhaps on their way to hit the Exit button).

**Question**

Is there anyway to determine that the event was raised because of the File Menu?  Any way to programatically determine if the File Menu is currently open?

Here's what I mean by the File Menu Screen:

[image: File Menu Screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Backstage UI provides two callbacks that can be used for tracking when the File menu is open and closed:

- onShow - The Backstage view is displayed which triggers the **OnShow** callback procedure.
- onHide - when the Backstage view is not longer visible.

The onShow attribute and the onHide attribute of the  element can point to code that performs that kind of action.

```
<backstage onShow="OnShow">
```

See [Customizing the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee815851%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#odc_office14_ta_CustomizeBackstageView_performingActions) for more information.

Comment: Is it possible to receive the backstage events onShow, onHide when using the ribbon designer? In the interface Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonOfficeMenu there are no such events. Is there a way to receive them?